# Java do-while detail

Tags: java, matrix, do-while

My code does an error but I don't know how to correct it:

```
public class Cenas {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //gera matrizes de tamanho aleatório com uns e zeros
    int a = 2;//(int)(Math.random() *3) + 1;
    int b  = 2;//(int)(Math.random() *3) + 1;
    int[][]matriz = new int [a][b];
    do{
        for (int i=0; i<a; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<b; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }while(matrizIdentidade(matriz)==true); //the error is in here!!! the ";"


public static boolean matrizIdentidade (int[][]m){
    boolean diagonal = false;
    if (m.length==m[0].length) //matriz.Testada[0] é o comprimento da matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
                if(i==j && m[i][j]==1)
                    if(i!=j && m[i][j]==0)
                        diagonal = true;
    return diagonal;
}
}
```

It generates random matrices and tells me if they are an identity matrix or not. I put the System.out.print and dimension 2 by 2 just for testing. The error makes my loop infinite...

";" on the line commented appears underlined in red (in Eclipse) giving me an error.

I humbly think that you are missing my question. I don't know if the statements in my methods are correct (I'm working on it), but what brings me here is that the ";" gives me an error: "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody". If that is due to my badly coded logic I apologized. But I think, instead, that indicates that I'm doing some syntax error on the do-while loop.

Comment: _My code does an error but I don't know how to correct it_ what error it throws?

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your code line by line, to figure out which calculations are going wrong.

Comment: the error is ";". I don't understand this error. I still haven't learn how to debug.

Comment: can you translate the comment to English and update you Question please ?

Comment: the only comment needed is the one already in english.

Comment: I updated my solution, check the new function `matrizIdentidade`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining the return value only by the last member

```
  diagonal = true;
```

Should be the opposite, you start assuming the matrix is the identity and return false when you check that it is not true.

```
if((i==j && m[i][j]!=1) || (i!=j && m[i][j]!=0)) {
   // this is not an identity matrix, so you can stop
   return false;
}
```

if the loop ends, the matrix is the identity so return `true`.

Comment: thank you for your input on the logic. Still I made my question clear. Please care to help me further.

Comment: Oh, apart from that, you did not close the `main` method. As your compiler says: `Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody` after the `while` line. In my opinion, given your level, you should work with easier codes.

Comment: LOL what a noob! It seems I'm too distracted from being tired. Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The loop do-while is infinite because it never get `matrizIdentidade(matriz)==true`.

Try to browse the elements of the matrix twice to check the two properties of a diagonal matrix. Try this please :

```
public static boolean matrizIdentidade (int[][]m){

    boolean diagonal1 = false, diagonal2 = false  ;

    if (m.length==m[0].length) //matriz.Testada[0] é o comprimento da matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
                    if(i!=j && m[i][j]==0)
                        diagonal1 = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
                    if(i==j && m[i][j]==1)
                        diagonal2 = true;

        if(diagonal1 == true && diagonal2 == true ) return true
        else return false; 
}
```

If the problem is related to the syntax of `do-while`check this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)
Snippet :

```
       do {
            System.out.println("Count is: "
                               + count);
            count++;
        } while (count < 11);
```